# multidimensional change of variables

Tags: probability, change-of-variable

If $\mathbf{X}=(X_1,...,X_n)$ s.t $X_i$'s are iid r.vs with $X_i\sim Ga(\alpha_i,\beta_i)$. Let $S=\sum_{j=1}^n X_j$ and $R_i={X_i\over S}$ 
 s.t $\mathbf{R}=(R_1,...,R_n)$. I have read that the density of $f_{\mathbf{R},S}(r_1,...,r_n,s)$ is $$f_{\mathbf{R},S}(r_1,...,r_n,s)=f_{\mathbf{X}}(r_1s,...,r_ns)s^{n-1}.$$
How did we make the variable change from $n$ to $n+1$ variables and should $|J|=s^{n}$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$S$ should be $\displaystyle\sum_{j=1}^n X_j.$ The joint distribution of $(X_1,\dots,X_n,S)$ is the same as that of $(X_1,\dots,X_n)\mathbb{I}(S=\displaystyle\sum_{j=1}^n X_j).$
$$f_{X_1,\dots,X_n,S}(x_1,\dots,x_n,s)=\begin{cases}\displaystyle\prod_{i=1}^ng(x_i;\alpha_i,\beta_i)\hspace{1cm}\text{if }x_i>0,\,\,s=\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^nx_i
\\0\hspace{4cm}\text{otherwise,}\end{cases}$$
where $g(.;\alpha_i,\beta_i)$ is the pdf of the $i^{\text{th}}$ Gamma distribution. Now we use transformation of random variables to get the required distribution. Let $(R_1,\dots,R_n,S)=h(X_1,\dots,X_n,S).$ The inverse transformation should be 
$(X_1,\dots,X_n,S)=(R_1S,\dots,R_nS,S).$ Then the Jacobian is

$$\begin{bmatrix}
s & 0 &\dots  &0  &r_1 \\ 
 0& s & 0 &\dots  &r_2 \\ 
 0&0  &s  &\dots  &r_3 \\ 
 \vdots& \vdots &  &\ddots  &\vdots \\ 
 0&  0& \dots &0  &1 
\end{bmatrix}$$

and so $|J|=s^{n}.$

Comment: Thank you. shouldn't $|J|=s^{n}$ since we have $n+1 \times n+1$ matrix

Comment: @Tresnom yes, sorry about that. Corrected.